# Calling an object's method within its object

Tags: javascript

I have my code like this where I am creating objects within an object using a function. As you can see I cannot access createObj as it is not yet defined. Using "this" did not help because the it will still be "window". I know one alternative is to use the New or create "obj1" property after creating object o, but is there any other way to do this?

```
o = {
createObj: function(){
//obj creation code
},
obj1: createObj()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could;

```
var o = (function() {
    function createObj() {
        //obj creation code
    }
    return {
        createObj: createObj,
        obj1: createObj()
    }
})();
```

Comment: @EugeneP you have a typo; console.log(o.obj); should be console.log(o.obj1);

Comment: Thanks Alex. I followed the above way and made it suit my code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
var o = {
  createObj: function(){
    //obj creation code
  }
}

o.obj1 = o.createObj();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var o = {
   createObj : function () {
        //obj creation code
        return "bl";
   }
}
Object.defineProperty(o, "obj", {
  get : function () { 
    return o.createObj();
  } 
});

console.log(o.obj)
```

another interesting case. using Object api.